# Guard with RSpec not functioning properly, it gets stuck in 14:39:11 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, guard

I'm trying to configure Guard to run the specs, but no matter what setup I do, the output is always the same: no tests running, only:

```
test_1           | 14:39:11 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
test_1           | 14:39:11 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/app'
```

When I run `bundle exec rspec` things work ok. This is the Guardfile:

```
guard :rspec, cmd: 'bundle exec rspec' do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails example
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb", (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" : "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")]}
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')                        { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }
  # Capybara request specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/}) do |m|
    "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb"
  end
end
```

and the `spec_helper`:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'shoulda/matchers'
# This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause
# this file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any
# files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, consider making
# a separate helper file that requires the additional dependencies and performs
# the additional setup, and require it from the spec files that actually need
# it.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
    #     be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
    #     # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
    # ...rather than:
    #     # => "be bigger than 2"
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  # This option will default to `:apply_to_host_groups` in RSpec 4 (and will
  # have no way to turn it off -- the option exists only for backwards
  # compatibility in RSpec 3). It causes shared context metadata to be
  # inherited by the metadata hash of host groups and examples, rather than
  # triggering implicit auto-inclusion in groups with matching metadata.
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups

  # The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
  # with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.
  #   # This allows you to limit a spec run to individual examples or groups
  #   # you care about by tagging them with `:focus` metadata. When nothing
  #   # is tagged with `:focus`, all examples get run. RSpec also provides
  #   # aliases for `it`, `describe`, and `context` that include `:focus`
  #   # metadata: `fit`, `fdescribe` and `fcontext`, respectively.
  #   config.filter_run_when_matching :focus
  #
  #   # Allows RSpec to persist some state between runs in order to support
  #   # the `--only-failures` and `--next-failure` CLI options. We recommend
  #   # you configure your source control system to ignore this file.
  #   config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"
  #
  #   # Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is
  #   # recommended. For more details, see:
  #   #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax/
  #   #   - http://www.teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
  #   #   - http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/#zero-monkey-patching-mode
  #   config.disable_monkey_patching!
  #
  #   # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  #   # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  #   # individual spec file.
  #   if config.files_to_run.one?
  #     # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
  #     # unless a formatter has already been configured
  #     # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
  #     config.default_formatter = "doc"
  #   end
  #
  #   # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  #   # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  #   # particularly slow.
  #   config.profile_examples = 10
  #
  #   # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  #   # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  #   # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #   #     --seed 1234
  #   config.order = :random
  #
  #   # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  #   # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  #   # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  #   # as the one that triggered the failure.
  #   Kernel.srand config.seed
  config.include(Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveModel, type: :model)
  config.include(Shoulda::Matchers::ActiveRecord, type: :model)
end
```

Perhaps there is some configuration missing that I'm not seeing.

----- EDIT -----

Running `bundle exec guard -d` gives me the following output:

```
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Notiffany: gntp not available (Please add "gem 'ruby_gntp'" to your Gemfile and run your app with "bundle exec".).
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Notiffany: growl not available (Unsupported platform "linux-gnu").
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Notiffany: terminal_notifier not available (Unsupported platform "linux-gnu").
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Notiffany: libnotify not available (Please add "gem 'libnotify'" to your Gemfile and run your app with "bundle exec".).
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Command execution: which notify-send
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Notiffany: notifysend not available (libnotify-bin package is not installed).
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Notiffany: notifu not available (Unsupported platform "linux-gnu").
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Command execution: {"ALTERNATE_EDITOR"=>"false"} emacsclient --eval '1'
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Notiffany: emacs not available (Emacs client failed).
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Notiffany: tmux not available (:tmux notifier is only available inside a TMux session.).
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Notiffany: file not available (No :path option given).
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Notiffany is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Command execution: which editor > /dev/null 2>&1
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Command execution: which nano > /dev/null 2>&1
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Command execution: which vi > /dev/null 2>&1
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Command execution: hash stty
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Guard starts all plugins
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Hook :start_begin executed for Guard::RSpec
test_1           | 17:56:37 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Hook :start_end executed for Guard::RSpec
test_1           | 17:56:37 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/app'
test_1           | 17:56:37 - DEBUG - Start interactor
```

Comment: Does it just hang or do you get a pry console that still responds [to commands](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Interacting-with-Guard)?

Comment: @max it doesn't respond to commands at all, it just seats there. The interesting part is that if I change a file it will run the specs

Comment: @max I've updated my question if you can take a look.